# Renaming directories at multiple levels using find from bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

I'm looping over the results of find, and I'm changing every one of those folders, so my problem is that when I encounter:
`/aaaa/logs/` and after that: `/aaaa/logs/bbb/logs`, when I try to `mv /aaaa/logs/bbb/logs /aaaa/log/bbb/log` it can't find the folder because it has already been renamed. That is, the output from `find` may report that the name is `/aaaa/logs/bbb/logs`, when the script previously moved output to `/aaaa/log/bbb/`.
Simple code:

```
#!/bin/bash
script_log="/myPath"
echo "Info" > $script_log
search_names_folders=`find /home/ -type d -name "logs*"`
while read -r line; do
      mv $line ${line//logs/log} >>$script_log 2>&1
done <<< "$search_names_folders"
```

My Solution is:

```
#!/bin/bash
script_log="/myPath"
echo "Info" > $script_log
search_names_folders=`find /home/ -type d -name "logs*"`
while read -r line; do
      number_of_occurrences=$(grep -o "logs" <<< "$line" | wc -l)
  if [ "$number_of_occurrences" != "1" ]; then
       real_path=${line//logs/log} ## get the full path, the suffix will be incorrect
       real_path=${real_path%/*} ## get the prefix until the last /
       suffix=${line##*/} ## get the real suffix
       line=$real_path/$suffix ## add the full correct path to line
       mv $line ${line//logs/log} >>$script_log 2>&1
  fi 
done <<< "$search_names_folders"
```

But its bad idea, Has anyone have other solutions?
Thanks!

Comment: `find` is not part of bash, and bash has nothing to do with the order of its output.

Comment: Also, **please** make an effort to write clearly. There are things that can be forgiven on account of not being a native speaker, but using "bcs" for "because" is not one of them.

Comment: Also, capturing `search_names_folders` in a scalar variable is simply wrong. File names can contain any character other than NUL, **including** newlines, so you can't tell the difference between a newline that separates two files or a newline that's actually part of a filename. The only way to accurately represent a list of arbitrary filenames inside a shell variable is for that variable to be an array. Think about someone doing `mkdir -p '$'\n/etc/passwd\n/logs'` -- that could ruin your whole day if you run a script that deletes things.

Comment: Also, as an aside: Putting `>>$script_log` on the inside of your loop is extremely inefficient compared to putting `>>"$script_log"` on the loop itself -- the former re-opens the output file once per `mv` command, the latter opens it only once and leaves it open for the loop's duration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-depth` option to `find`. This makes it process directory contents before it processes the directory itself.

Comment: ...though that's not the only fix necessary, as the OP's code currently runs the substitution everywhere in the path, not only at the leaf filename.

Comment: ...thus, if they had `hello/logs/world/logs`, their first `mv` would try to rename it to `hello/log/world/log`, as opposed to renaming to `hello/logs/world/log` first.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks! But still, As Charles Duffy said, When I try to mv the sub directory first, it will work, but then agian the parent folder won't be correct path so mv will not work.

Comment: You should just substitute the last `log` in the pathname, so it doesn't rename the directory until after it renames all the files in the directory.